# Is there a non-iterative equivalent of this expression in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

The expression is:

```
for i=1:n
    X(:,i) = [P{i}(:)];
end
```

where X is a DxN matrix and P is a cell-array.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that. P{i} is a "[2x2 double]" which I think is a matrix. I obtained it using mat2cell. From my understanding, mat2cell returns a cell-array of matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you obtained the cell array via `mat2cell`, you may be wanting to arrange blocks of an image into the columns of an array `X`. This can be achieved in a single step using the command [IM2COL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2col.html)

```
%# rearrange the large array so that each column of X
%# corresponds to the 4 pixels of each 2-by-2 block
X = im2col(largeArray,[2 2],'distinct');
```

Comment: excellent, this was exactly what I was looking for ! And indeed, the context of the above code is PCA image analysis.

Answer (score 3):

```
reshape(cat(3,P{:}),[numel(P{1}) n])
```

Of course, the above solution is just for fun. I would recommend profiling both solutions and only using this one if it has a significant performance advantage.

Maintenance and readability are also very important factors to consider when writing code.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with:

```
P{1} = [ 1 2; 3 4];
P{2} = [ 7 8; 9 10];
P{3} = [ 11 12; 13 14];
X = [P{:}]

X =

     1     2     7     8    11    12
     3     4     9    10    13    14
```

Then some sort of reshape() to get to where you want to be.